# Converting code from MATLAB to C++

Tags: c++, matlab, function

The code below is written in MATLAB and runs correctly in MATLAB and I have been trying to convert it C++ but I kept getting an error. I am trying to write this program in form of a function so I can recall it in the **int main function**

```
function flow = fcoeff_ridwansa( Re, RelRough )
    if (Re < 4000)
       FCL = (64./Re);
       flow = FCL;
    else
       for i = 1:length(Re)
           for j = 1:length(RelRough)
               FCT_guess = 1;
               tolerance = 1;
               while tolerance > 1e-14 
                   FCT_cal = 1/(-2*log10((RelRough(j)/3.7) + (2.51/(Re(i)*sqrt(FCT_guess)))))^2;
                   tolerance = abs(FCT_cal-FCT_guess);
                   FCT_guess = FCT_cal;
                   flow(i,j) = FCT_cal;
               end
           end
       end
   end
   end
```

This is my attempt in C++

```
double f(double Re[], double RelRough[]){
double fcoeff;
const double lengthRelRough = sizeof(RelRough) / sizeof(RelRough[0]);
const double lengthRe = sizeof(Re) / sizeof(Re[0]);

if (*Re < 4000.0) {
        fcoeff = 64 / *Re;
    }

else {
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthRe; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < lengthRelRough; ++j) {
            double fct_guess = 1;
            double tolerance = 1;
            while (tolerance > 1e-14) {
                double h = (-2 * log10((RelRough[j] / 3.7) + (2.51 / (Re[i] * sqrt(fct_guess)))));
                double fct_cal = 1 / pow(h, 2);
                tolerance = abs(fct_cal - fct_guess);
                fct_guess = fct_cal;
                fcoeff = fct_cal;
            }
        }
    }
}
return fcoeff;
}

int main()
{
    double f(double Re[], double RelRough[]);
    double r[] = { 600.0 }, n[] = { 0.002 };
    std::cout << f(r, n) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post your own attempt in C++ so we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 2):

```
const double lengthRelRough = sizeof(RelRough) / sizeof(RelRough[0]);
const double lengthRe = sizeof(Re) / sizeof(Re[0]);
```

Neither of these statements will work as you expect them to because RelRough and Re are pointers not arrays.

It's not possible to pass an array to a function in C++.

You might find this easier if you used a vector instead of an array.

Comment: Do you have a link on how to use that because I'm a beginner in C++

Comment: google? I've no particular recommendation. I think vectors will be a bit closer to what you expect from your experience in MATLAB. Arrays in C++ are tricky, vectors are easier.

Comment: Vectors for sure. Armadillo library can also be useful. It's very similar to Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

MatLab and C++ code syntax is completely different and inserting Matlab code into a .cpp file will most certainly not compile. For example this is how you write functions in C++:

```
/*
<type> <function name> (<type> <argument1 name>, <argument2 name>)
{
  <body>
  return <return value>;
}

In example:                            */
int sum(int first_number, int second_number)
{
  int result = first_number + second_number;
  return result;
}
```

There are more syntax errors in your example, in example the for loop in C++ is different.

However, if you have no time/will to learn C++ you might want to check out this [tutorial](https://www.mathworks.com/videos/automatically-converting-matlab-code-to-c-code-96483.html) which is an official MatLab tutorial for automatically converting MatLab code to C code (which is compatible/close with C++ in general).

Comment: There are no syntax errors in his/her code - it's plain matlab. Most importantly the OP will have to use arrays or vectors or similar container and handling that will become the biggest difference. Otherwise it's a pretty straightforward and simple code.

Comment: If he tries to use that as C++ and not MatLab code then that's not valid syntax.

Comment: I understood he/she are asking for C++ translation of this matlab piece. And that they tried but haven't posted their C++ code which would be better altogether. The OP quite clearly states it's matlab. It is indeed.

Comment: It is in MATLAB Niteraleph I just need to code it C++ and I have added what I wrote in C++ in the question already

Answer (score 0):

If performance is critical, using `std::vectors` may be slow.

The fastest (but unsafe) way will be using pointers to arrays with their size:

`f(double * Re, long sizeRe, double * RelRough, long sizeRelRough)`

Then access elements just as arrays: `Re[i]`

Also you can read `codegen` help, that generate c++ code, at least for copy-past.